# javascript function running without being called

Tags: javascript, function-calls

I wonder why, as soon as the page loads, the function `btw_bijtellen ()` is called. I wanted to call it by clicking...

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById (id);
}

function btw_bijtellen () {
    window.alert("we want to calculate something after clicking th button");
}

$("bereken").onclick = btw_bijtellen ();
```

Answer (score 24):

You've added `()` which causes the function to execute.

For example:

```
var myFunc1 = function() {
    alert('Hello');
}(); // <--- () causes self execution

var myFunc2 = function() {
    return 5 + 5;
};

var some_value = myFunc2(); // <--- Again () causes execution (you'd expect this one)
```

In your case, as mentioned in comments you're basically telling the `onclick` to set its value to the return value of the function.

If you drop the `()` it should run as expected.

Comment: By the way, for @bert, this means your onclick handler is assigned "undefined" - because running this function which returns "undefined" assigns this result to onclick.

Comment: @Lloyd So only parenthesis when declaring or calling, all the rest (which leafs only assigning?) without parenthesis?

Comment: Declaring or calling yes. For assignment just drop them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the function to be called on click then use

```
$("bereken").on('click', btw_bijtellen);
```

## Update (As per query from WAO)

If you need to pass the argument, then you need to specify as the second argument. the `$.on()` gets the data in the `event` handler

```
$("bereken").on('click', {key1: value1, key2: value2, keyn: valuen}, btw_bijtellen);
```

where, you can get your parameters from `event.data`

```
var function = btw_bijtellen(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    console.log(data);

    var key1 = event.data.key1;
    console.log(key1);  // this will output value1
}
```

Have a read on this link [jQuery $.on() api](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: what if you want to pass an argument to 'btw_bijtellen' function?

Answer (score 1):

Putting `()` after a function name is how you call it.

If you want to assign the `btw_bijtellen` to `onclick` then remove the `()` from the last line of the code in the question.

With the `()` there, you are calling the function and assigning its *return value* to `onclick`. Since that function has no `return` statement, that value will be `undefined` which is not what you want.